# How can I call an api before user login

Tags: ajax, api

I have a custom login, in which I have 2 apis: The first to post a user phone, and the second to post the user pin to verify the phone.

The main issues is that these 2 apis, which has the following url (domain.com/api/user/verify_phone) are not working because they are redirected to the /login page.

When I call the same url after the user is authenticated it works... but I need it before the login of course. How can I do that? Please help!

**I may found that the bug in the functions.php on the theme**, there I have created a function to handle all the redirections of the login, this is the code:

```
function login_redirect(){
global $pagenow;
     if( 'wp-admin' != preg_split('/\//',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1] ){
        if(preg_split('/\//',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1] == '/api/'){
            exit();
        }else if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/login/') {
            if (!checkUserStatus()){
                wp_redirect('https://learn.fractalup.com/login/');
                exit();
            }
        }
 }
add_action('parse_request','login_redirect');
```

So with these I try to redirect all call to make sure users log in and I tried to make the apis call go through but there are still giving a 302 redirection error. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: How are those APIs implemented? There's no code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a slight mistake on your "if" condition

```
$result = preg_split('/\//','domain.com/api/user/verify_phone');
var_dump($result);
```

Results in:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "domain.com"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "api"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "user"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "verify_phone"
}
```

So the result at [1] is "api", but you are checking for "/api/" on the fourth line of your code sample.